# how to create monthly and season 24 hours average table using pandas

Tags: pandas, time, pandas-resample

I have a dataframe with 2 columns: `Date` and `LMP` and there are totals of 8760 rows. This is the dummy dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': pd.date_range('2023-01-01 00:00', '2023-12-31 23:00', freq='1H'), 'LMP': np.random.randint(10, 20, 8760)})
```

I extract `month` from the date and then created the `season` column for the specific dates. Like this

```
df['month'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df['Date']).month
season = []
for i in df['month']:
    if i <= 2 or i == 12:
        season.append('Winter')
    elif 2 < i <= 5:
        season.append('Spring')
    elif 5 < i <= 8:
        season.append('Summer')
    else:
        season.append('Autumn')
df['Season'] = season
df2 = df.groupby(['month']).mean()
df3 = df.groupby(['Season']).mean()
print(df2['LMP'])
print(df3['LMP'])
```

Output:

```
**month**
1     20.655113
2     20.885532
3     19.416946
4     22.025248
5     26.040606
6     19.323863
7     51.117965
8     51.434093
9     21.404680
10    14.701989
11    20.009590
12    38.706160

**Season**
Autumn    18.661426
Spring    22.499365
Summer    40.856845
Winter    26.944382
```

But I want the output to be in 24 hour average for both `monthly` and `seasonal`.
Desired Output:
for **seasonal 24 hours average**
[image]

For **monthyl 24 hours average**
[image]

Note: in the monthyl 24 hour average columns are months(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12) and rows are hours(starting from 0).
Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
df['hour']=pd.DatetimeIndex(df['Date']).hour
dft = df[['Season', 'hour', 'LMP']]
dftg = dft.groupby(['hour', 'Season'])['LMP'].mean()
dftg.reset_index().pivot(index='hour', columns='Season')
```

result:

[image]